# Android Development Eclipse - Cant Create a New Android Project - Mac OS

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos, project

I have an issue creating a new android project using the eclipse wizard, everything worked fine by yesterday. had a few project working. Now, when i press "Finish" on the final step of the wizard it remain open and an empty project with white-marked packages is added to the work branch,
I tried to reinstall eclipse and it's sdk+plug, still nothing.

Would really appreciate your assistance,
Thank you in advance

Ben

Answer (score 1):

It might be because of jre update. On Linux, SVN plugin used to fail on hhtps connections when open JDK was used.

To find out the problem try checking your workspace log under /workspace/.metadata/
I suggest you to delete the log file then start your eclipse and try to produce the error.
Most probably a plugin is receiving an exception which is not handled (or handled in a bad way) and probably you can find out whats wrong from the log file.